# Is there a way to instrument jar files with JaCoCo Java API?

Tags: java, api, jacoco

I'm migrating from Emma . to JaCoCo and everything is working fine so far. One of the pieces I'm struggling with is a part in the code EMMA is instrumenting a set of jar files from some sub projects that are dependencies on the main project.

On EMMA the code looked like this:

```
InstrProcessor processor = InstrProcessor.create();
processor.setInstrPath(getFilePaths(jars), false);
processor.setOutMode(OutMode.OUT_MODE_OVERWRITE);
processor.setMetaOutFile(metadataFile.getAbsolutePath());
processor.setMetaOutMerge(merge);
processor.run();
```

The closest I found for JaCoCo was Instrumenter class but doesn't seem to take files just input streams. There are no hints in the JavaDoc about it working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [JavaDoc of a method `org.jacoco.core.instr.Instrumenter#instrumentAll`](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/org/jacoco/core/instr/Instrumenter.html#instrumentAll(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)):

> Creates a instrumented version of the given resource depending on its type. Class files and the **content of archive files are instrumented**. All other files are copied without modification.

i.e.

```
try (
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("input.jar");
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output.jar");
) {
  instrumenter.instrumentAll(in, out, "input.jar");
}
```

and this is exactly how [instrumentation of JAR files implemented](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/v0.8.1/org.jacoco.cli/src/org/jacoco/cli/internal/commands/Instrument.java#L82-L98) in [JaCoCo Command Line Interface](https://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html).